# openssl 0.9.8 EVP EVP_PKEY_CTX not defined

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I am using openssl 0.9.8 (and currently cant change to a higher version).
i am using the openssl evp api (evp - high-level cryptographic functions )
to encrypt so data with aes and the key with rsa.

a call of:

```
EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
```

results in an compiling error:

```
error: 'EVP_PKEY_CTX' was not declared in this scope
```

according to this  [link](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg26545.html)

> VP_PKEY_CTX is only in 1.0.0 and later.

But evp allready existed in 0.9.8.
so what type should i use instead of EVP_PKEY_CTX for my pointer variable *ctx?

Comment: `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id` is part of 1.0.0 too. So you might have to abandon `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id` and friends (or port the support into 0.9.8). See the OpenSSL docs at [`EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_PKEY_CTX_new.html).

Answer (score 2):

> But evp allready existed in 0.9.8. so what type should i use instead of EVP_PKEY_CTX for my pointer variable *ctx?

`EVP_PKEY` and friends may be available in OpenSSL 0.9.8. For example:

```
$ grep -R EVP_PKEY_new *
apps/req.c:     if ((pkey=EVP_PKEY_new()) == NULL) goto end;
apps/apps.c:    pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
crypto/evp/p_lib.c:EVP_PKEY *EVP_PKEY_new(void)
...
```

But I don't see where `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id` and `EVP_PKEY_CTX` are available in OpenSSL 0.9.8. This is consistent with what the docs are telling you.

```
$ grep -R EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id *
$

$ grep -R EVP_PKEY_CTX *
crypto/cms/cms_sd.c:    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl(pctx, -1, EVP_PKEY_OP_SIGN,
crypto/cms/cms_sd.c:    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl(pctx, -1, EVP_PKEY_OP_SIGN,
$
```